# How to dockerize vue3 laravel9 application?

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I am developping a vue3 laravel9 SPA.
The app is presently running in dev and in production on a web hosting.

I would like to distribute it without the need of a web hosting as a dockerized application but I do not know docker that much.

I base my approach on this example : https://github.com/AveryHowell/docker-laravel-vue
I just copied from the example to my app

laravel/nginx (folder)
laravel/docker-compose.yml (file)
laravel/laravel.dockerfile (file)

vue/nginx.conf (file)
vue/vue.dockerfile (file)

The changes I made to this example are very limited.

First I changed the version of mysql in laravel/docker-compose.yml to mariadb:10.3.37

```
#Mysql DB
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.3.37
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
    volumes:
      - ../mysql:/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
```

This version is the one I presently use and avoid some trouble with default values in json columns.

Secondly I changed the database config and some urls in .env

```
APP_NAME='my application'
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Wh2GGnDZ6YLEjNghheIX4qL+6P9lHuS8sO03L/pCufA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_API_URL=http://localhost/api/
APP_API_DEV_URL=http://localhost:8080/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
SPA_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

After that I used these commands

```
 docker-compose up -d
 docker-compose exec laravel composer update 
 docker-compose exec laravel composer install
 docker-compose exec laravel composer dump-autoload

 docker-compose exec laravel php artisan key:generate
 docker-compose exec laravel php artisan config:cache

 docker-compose exec laravel php artisan migrate:fresh
```

I had the tables created in mariadb

but when I visited localhost:8080 as said in the example, I got this message

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> ```
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.
> ```

What is wrong?

EDIT AFTER FIRST COMMENT

```
[jaaf@localhost laravel]$ docker container ls --filter label=com.docker.compose.project
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS                                         NAMES
5719d4b36179   laravel-webserver   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   44 minutes ago   Up 44 minutes                   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp             webserver
9b88d442636c   laravel-vue         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   44 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 51 seconds ago                                                 vue
37743ac9307f   laravel             "docker-php-entrypoi…"   44 minutes ago   Up 44 minutes                   9000/tcp                                      laravel
1cf764c56ad0   mariadb:10.3.37     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   44 minutes ago   Up 44 minutes                   0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp, :::33061->3306/tcp   db
[jaaf@localhost laravel]$
```

Comment: docker container ls --filter label=com.docker.compose.project,print this.

Comment: Please see addition to the end of the post

Comment: Use docker logs to see what is the issue. Your vue container has crashed.

Comment: docker logs <laravel-vue id> tells me in the first line missing script "serve"

Comment: I replaced serve with dev. The container no longer crashes but the vue app doesn't appear in the browser.